# Output in the middle of a simple_form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml, simple-form-for

I have a simple_form using simple_form_for. It works fine.

I want to add a line that looks like:

**Locked?**    True

in the middle. I can produce it with:

```
= f.label "Locked?"
= f.label @client.access_locked?
```

However, this doesn't add a new line, and messes everything else up.

I'd like to have the equivalent of a f.input line, except it's output instead of input:

```
= f.output label: "Locked?", value: @client.access_locked?
```

or something. How do I do this?

EDIT:

Currently, I have this:

```
= simple_form_for @client, :url => admin_client_path(@client) do |f|
  = f.input :email, :input_html => {:autocomplete => "off"}
  .user_profile
    %dl
      %dt Locked
      %dd=  @client.access_locked?
  = f.button :submit, 'Update', :class => 'button'
```

Which produces this:

[image]

I'd like it all to line up... But this is the best I've got so far...

Comment: Is the only problem lack of a new line? If so, why not wrap it in a `div`?

Comment: It's also not spaced the same as the rest of the form...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the bootstrap class `form-control-static` ?
See https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_forms_inputs2.asp